# Link Bokeh Dropdown Widget to the bar chart

Tags: python, bokeh, bokehjs

I created a dropdown widget and a bar chart, I want to filter my values based on the "categories". How do I link both the dropdown and the graph?

```
#import essential Libs
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Grid, HBar, LinearAxis, Plot
from bokeh.models import Dropdown
from bokeh.resources import INLINE
import bokeh.io
from bokeh import *
bokeh.io.output_notebook(INLINE)
from bokeh.layouts import column, row

#create new df with to groupby Genre and count of Ratings
genre_view = data[["Rating", "Genres", "Category"]]
genre_view = genre_view.groupby(by = "Genres", as_index = False).count()
genre_view = genre_view.rename(columns = {"Rating": "Total Ratings"})
y = genre_view["Total Ratings"]

#sort values froms largest to smallest
genre_view.sort_values(by ="Total Ratings", axis = 0, inplace = True, ascending=False)

#Dropdown Widget
menu = data['Category']
menu2 = menu.to_list()
dropdown = Dropdown(label = 'Category Dropdown', button_type='warning',menu=menu2)

#create bar chart
p = figure(title = "Most Rated Genres by Category", 
           x_range = genre_view["Genres"], 
           x_axis_label = "Genres",
           sizing_mode = "stretch_both",
           y_axis_label = "Ratings")

#use vbar function
p.vbar(x = genre_view["Genres"],
       bottom = 0,
       top = genre_view["Total Ratings"],  
       line_color = "black", 
       fill_color = "#4c7bd3")


#45 degree offset of xlabels
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = math.pi/4

#show(p)
show(row(p, dropdown))
```

**Current output (but drop down doesn't work)**
[image: Current output (but drop down doesn't work)]

Comment: Widgets don't do anything on their own. You would need to write and add a `CustomJS` callback to update the range factors appropriately. See [JavaScript callbacks](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html)

Comment: Thanks for responding, the thing is I am pretty new to this and I don't know how to write the JS callback, the original documentation is really specific to dropdowns. This seems really easy to pull off but I am not proficient enough to do it.

Comment: not just js callbacks. you could create connection with python too